# Dynamic HTML causes libraries to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I can't get this dynamically created content working with **jQuery Slider** and **jscolor**. The library functions are ignored. I'm guessing it's something to do with the order that things are processed in. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Here's a simplified example of the failing code.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <title>Test dynamic code and jscolor</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addcontent() {
            document.getElementById('colordiv').innerHTML = '<input id="valColourRGB" class="color" />';
            document.getElementById('sliderdiv').innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="p_slidernum" id="colT" name="valColourT" value="200" /><div id="colTslider"></div>';
        }

        $(function() {
            $( "#colTslider" ).slider({
                value: 100,
                min: 0,
                max: 255,
                slide: function( event, ui) {
                    $( "#colT" ).val( ui.value );
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="addcontent();">
    <div id="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="sliderdiv"></div>
</body>
```

If I manually move the INPUT tags into the DIVs it works fine, but why doesn't this work?

Comment: Any ideas about the jscolor issue? Thanks for all the responses on the slider problem. That works beautifully now.:-)

Comment: @Headforthehills If the answers helped you solve your problem, please choose the one that is the best and mark it as the correct answer (using the tickmark on the left of the answer). This is how it works here. If you have a different problem, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the slider after injecting the html.

http://jsfiddle.net/p46cs/

```
 function addcontent() {
    document.getElementById('colordiv').innerHTML = '<input id="valColourRGB" class="color" />';
    document.getElementById('sliderdiv').innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="p_slidernum" id="colT" name="valColourT" value="200" /><div id="colTslider"></div>';
     $( "#colTslider" ).slider({
            value: 100,
            min: 0,
            max: 255,
            slide: function( event, ui) {
                $( "#colT" ).val( ui.value );
            }
        });
    }

addcontent();
```

Answer (score 0):

`load` will fire later than the `DOMContentLoaded` that jQuery's `.ready()` depends on (using `$(function)` is equivalent to that).

One way of fixing your code is removing `onload` from `body` (you should not use this method called inline event handlers anyway) and calling `addContent` like this:

```
    $(function() {
        addContent();

        $( "#colTslider" ).slider({
            value: 100,
            min: 0,
            max: 255,
            slide: function( event, ui) {
                $( "#colT" ).val( ui.value );
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why would anyone down vote this answer? It is correct as any of the others

Comment: @Rui I was the victim of some mass-downvoting, but the system removed them. Lots of angry people here :).

Answer (score 0):

the jquery may be trying to assign the events before you load the content into dom.  Try putting the call to addContent() in the ready method.

here is a bin
http://jsbin.com/eYaqoci/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

window.onload will happen after jQuery's ready event, what that means is that:

```
$( "#colTslider" ).slider({
                value: 100,
                min: 0,
                max: 255,
                slide: function( event, ui) {
                    $( "#colT" ).val( ui.value );
                }
```

will run before addContent(), meaning $('#colTslider') won't match any element.
(See http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready)

You can call addContent before you setup the slider in jQuery's ready event handler ($(function(){...}) and it should start working:

```
$(function(){
$('#colordiv').html('<input id="valColourRGB" class="color" />');
$('#sliderdiv').html('<input type="text" class="p_slidernum" id="colT" name="valColourT" value="200" /><div id="colTslider"></div>');

$( "#colTslider" ).slider({
    value: 100,
    min: 0,
    max: 255,
    slide: function( event, ui) {
        $( "#colT" ).val( ui.value );
     });
});
```